# ASP.NET MVC 5.0 Complex Model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with the name "Create". This view gets the "SchoolViewModel" which contains two classes:

```
public class SchoolViewModel
{
    public List<Teacher> ListTeacher { get; set; }
    public List<SchoolClass> ListSchoolClass { get; set; }
    public ClassComplete ClassComplete { get; set; }
}
```

Each list in "SchoolViewModel" provides data from a database.

At the "Create" page you should be able now to select a teacher and class (DropDownList). The "ClassComplete" object contains the two classes (Teacher and SchoolClass) and the roomname

```
public class ClassComplete
{
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public SchoolClass SchoolClass { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

I want only to post the "ClassComplete" object.

My ActionResult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ClassComplete cp)
{
        // Do something
        return View();
}
```

Edit:
Razor View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListTeacher[0].TeacherName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListSchoolClass[0].ClassName)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cl.RoomName)<br />

        <input type="submit" value="Click" />
    }
```

Is this the right way ?

best regards

Comment: What does your Razor look like?

Comment: I edit the main post for razor view

Comment: Can you show me what your `@model` directive looks like? I don't see `cl` anywhere

Comment: @model WebApplication8.Models.SchoolViewModel

Answer (score 2):

If you want to POST only `ClassComplete` model you will need to indicate the binding prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="ClassComplete")] ClassComplete cp)
{
    // Do something
    return View();
}
```

and in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClassComplete.RoomName)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
}
```

The `TextBoxFor` will generate the following input field in the resulting markup:

```
<input type="text" name="ClassComplete.RoomName" />
```

Notice the `name` of the input field. That's the reason why you need to indicate this prefix in your controller action.

This will also work for the other properties if you want to send them you just need to include the corresponding input fields:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClassComplete.SchoolClass.SomeProperty)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClassComplete.Teacher.SomeOtherProperty)
...
```